# java android upload jpeg image

Tags: php, android, jpeg

I am trying to upload a jpeg to a server. The file uploads fine but metadata is missing and it can't be viewed. When I download the image to my desktop it only shows the file associtation. If I open it in photoshop I can see the image. Once I save it, it works fine.

I am using Retrofit 1.8 to upload the image. I am using SoundCloud Crop to crop the image.

I have tried to read the the exif data in android before I upload it, but true to form android is being android with its many api screw ups, I mean levels.

Php reports

> [30-Jun-2017 22:05:25 Europe/Dublin] PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(jrProfile_1_profile_image.jpg): File not supported in /home/jamroom/sites/theflirtapp.com/public_html/modules/jrOpus/account.php on line 87 [3]

```
private void changeAvatar() {
    List<Intent> otherImageCaptureIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ResolveInfo> otherImageCaptureActivities = getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), 0);

    for (ResolveInfo info : otherImageCaptureActivities) {
        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        captureIntent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(tempOutputFile));
        otherImageCaptureIntents.add(captureIntent);
    }

    Intent selectImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    selectImageIntent.setType("image/*");

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(selectImageIntent, "Choose Avatar");
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, otherImageCaptureIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[otherImageCaptureActivities.size()]));

    startActivityForResult(chooser, REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        tempOutputFile.delete();
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE) {
        Uri outputFile;
        Uri tempFileUri = Uri.fromFile(tempOutputFile);

        if(data != null && (data.getAction() == null || !data.getAction().equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE))) {
            outputFile = data.getData();
        }
        else {
            outputFile = tempFileUri;
        }

        new Crop(outputFile)
                .asSquare()
                .output(tempFileUri)
                .start(this);
    }
    else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
        avatarProgressFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bus.post(new Account.ChangeAvatarRequest(Uri.fromFile(tempOutputFile)));

    }
}
```

Here is the array received in $_FILES

```
Array ( 
 [image] => Array ( 
    [name] => temp-image.jpg 
    [type] => image/jpeg 
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/jrwQIld9 
    [size] => 231047 
    [error] => 0 
    ) 
 )
```